# Are 耳光 and 巴掌 the same?

Tags: meaning, word

There is this sentence in [this story 沙漠里的朋友](http://chinese-at-ease.com/friends-in-desert-learn-chinese-story/): 今天我的好朋友打了我一巴掌.

Here, can I replace 巴掌 with 耳光?

Answer (score 5):

耳光

**ABC**

> N.
>
> box on the ears; slap on the face

巴掌

> N.
>
> palm of the hand

While they are inherently different, `打…巴掌` and `打…耳光` are roughly the same.

Consider these two example sentences from **A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> 打他一巴掌
>
> dǎ tā yī bāzhang
>
> give him a slap

> 打耳光
>
> dǎ ěrguāng
>
> slap sb.'s face; box sb.'s ears

The only difference might be is that 耳光 could alude to a specific hit/slap/punch to the ears.

Comment: also note use of verb: 扇 (iciba:（用手掌打） strike with the palm of the hand; slap slap sb. in the face; box sb.'s ears 扇耳光 (jukuu:扇了他一个耳光)

Answer (score 2):

### 巴掌

[image: Hands]

### 耳光

[image: Slap]

That's the difference...

Comment: I think OP's question is more of a question of whether 打…巴掌 and 打…耳光 are interchangeable. Nice pictures, though.

Answer (score 1):

耳光 means a hit on face
巴掌, when talking about hit, means a hit by palm, but maybe on face or other parts of your body
also, 巴掌 means palm as noun